# Angular 5 http interceptor not intercepting

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-http-interceptors

I've got a correct JWT token stored in local storage and an interceptor that I blatantly copied from a tutorial. However, it doesn't intercept and add headers to requests.

Here's where I make a request:

https://github.com/Marred/Informakcja/blob/master/Informakcja-client/src/app/services/information.service.ts

here's the interceptor:

https://github.com/Marred/Informakcja/blob/master/Informakcja-client/src/app/services/token.interceptor.ts

and my appmodule - I'm pretty sure it's correctly imported:

https://github.com/Marred/Informakcja/blob/master/Informakcja-client/src/app/app.module.ts

When I make a request I expect the interceptor to log messages that I specified to console and add the token to header, it doesn't do that though and I've got no idea why :/ I checked the code with some other tutorials found online and didn't see any differences capable of breaking my code. I also don't have enough experience with Angular to debug it properly.

Any help would be much apprecieated.

Comment: Links are dead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing couple of things wrongly here:

Interceptors are used with HttpClientModule not with HttpModule. You are using `HttpModule`. You need to change to `HttpClientModule`

1. Add `HttpClientModule` in imports array in `app.module.ts`
2. Import `HttpClient` in your `authentication.service.ts` and take its reference in its constructor.

Refer below code:

```
  //app.module.ts
    import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
    .
    .
    .
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
       .
       .
       .
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        .
        .
        .,
        HttpClientModule, //add here
        RouterModule.forRoot([
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
          { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
          { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
          { path: 'add-information', component: AddInformationComponent },
          { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ], { useHash: true })
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: 'BASE_URL', useValue: 'https://some URL/' },
        UserService,
        InformationService,
        AuthenticationService,
        AlertService,
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: TokenInterceptor,
          multi: true
        }
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

and

```
//information.service.ts and authentication.service.ts

import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'; //added import
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class InformationService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) { } //made changes in cunstructor

  add(link: string, title: string, description: string) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/Information', { link: link, title: title, description: description })
    .map((response: Response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
  }
}
```

make similar changes in authentication.service.ts